# Using FontAwecome icon in Flask table

Tags: python, pandas, flask, font-awesome

I have a pandas dataframe that I'm displaying as HTML in my Flask app and would like to add a Font Awesome icon as a column in that table and repeat it based on a count for each group. For example, in this scenario:

| Group | Count | Icon |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 |  |
| B | 2 |  |

I want the icon to be repeated once for Group A and twice for Group B. I'm able display icons in my navbar after downloading the flask-fontawesome package. The unicode/`<i>` tag (not sure which one is needed) are:

- &#xf091;
- <i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i>

Comment: maybe first add `HTML` with icon to `DataFrame` and later generate table. And don't forget to add `CSS` in Flask template. OR send dataframe to template and write own function to generate table in template.

Answer (score 1):

- same way as you would include a font-awesome icon in HTML.  Within a `<span>` with appropriate `class`
- repeat `<span>` as many times as required
- consider need to undo escaping of **<** and **>**
- this is running in Jupyter,  but same would be true for **flask**

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'B'], 'Count': [1, 2]})

df = df.assign(Icon=df["Count"].apply(lambda n: n*'<span class="fab fa-docker"></span>'))

from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(df.to_html().replace("&lt;","<").replace("&gt;",">")))
```

[image]

#### integrated into `flask`

- same code used to generate font awesome icons based on **Count**
- undone escaping of **<** and **>**
- included link to needed CDN for font awesome
- simple approach of using f-string to generate a html document

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'B'], 'Count': [1, 2]})
    df = df.assign(Icon=df["Count"].apply(lambda n: n*'<span class="fab fa-docker"></span>'))

    return f"""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <title>SO example</title>
</head>
<body>
    {df.to_html().replace("&lt;","<").replace("&gt;",">")}
    
</body>
</html>"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=3000)
```

Comment: Do you know how to make this show in flask? I was able to repeat the icon tag the appropriate amount of times in my dataframe, but the table still shows the tags when I run my app. From my df, I got my header and data: 

header = tuple(df.columns) 
data = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]

Then I added them to my HTML:

{% for header in headings %}
{% for row in data %}

Comment: I've updated to show using **flask**. have not gone to lengths of defining a template or anything